# What is "threshold brook" in Keats' 'The Human Seasons'

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

I don't understand the meaning of **threshold brook** in Keats's poem "[The Human Seasons](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173737)":

> Four Seasons fill the measure of the year;
>        There are four seasons in the mind of man:
>   He has his lusty Spring, when fancy clear
>        Takes in all beauty with an easy span:
>   He has his Summer, when luxuriously
>        Spring's honied cud of youthful thought he loves
>   To ruminate, and by such dreaming high
>        Is nearest unto heaven: quiet coves
>   His soul has in its Autumn, when his wings
>        He furleth close; contented so to look
>   On mists in idleness—to let fair things
>        Pass by unheeded as **a threshold brook**.
>   He has his Winter too of pale misfeature,
>   Or else he would forego his mortal nature.

Is it "a small stream running close to someone's door, or close to a wicket gate"? I doubt that, but this is the only interpretation I could come up with.

P.S. Or is it "a small stream that lies out of sight beyond some *threshold*" - say, a mound or hill or just a steep bank?

Googling for `"threshold brook" "meaning"` brings up boatloads of bloated literary criticism, and I need just the basic sense of the phrase.

P.P.S. I found one interpretation: "[a river that passes by a cottage door](https://books.google.ru/books?id=5MLnr1BvaIEC&lpg=PA490&ots=Rm98uWRhSw&dq=What%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9Cthreshold%20brook%E2%80%9D%20in%20Keats&hl=ru&pg=PA490#v=onepage&q=What%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9Cthreshold%20brook%E2%80%9D%20in%20Keats&f=false)" ("The Works of John Keats", Wordsworth Editions, 1994, page 490) after the question had been closed. Seems like I hadn't been meticulous enough.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Literary Criticism / interpretation of a "one-off" poetic usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree; but I'm also upvoting the question because it was asked in good faith, by a user who assumed it might have an ordinary prosaic meaning he could not fix.

Comment: @StoneyB: Depends how you see it, I suppose. I'm influenced by two aspects in particular. 1) - practically every line in the poem contains obscure figurative references, and 2) OP could have guessed "threshold brook" wasn't a standard collocation from the mere fact that googling it *brings up boatloads of **bloated literary criticism***. Why would that be the case if it was a "normal" usage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you google *wings he furleth* you get the same result; but *furl + wings* is a common collocation. You don't know these things until you know these things. Just in case you misunderstood: I did vote to close the question, because I don't think there's anything more to be said here that's of any use to anybody; but I think such questions may be asked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the critical reviews I chanced upon merely mentioned "a threshold brook" as something self-evident. There was no specific discussion about its meaning, so I thought it was a trivial thing.

Comment: I think this is a valid question about the word "threshold" on a literal level.

Comment: @StoneyB, CopperKettle: I don't fundamentally disagree with the fact of the question being *asked*. And I've upvoted the answer because it restricts itself to pointing out that "threshold brook" has no established meaning beyond the dictionary definitions of each word in isolation. I think it should be closed because I don't believe ELL users should be "formally" voting on "answers" offering different interpretations. But I would never endorse votes to *delete* the question, and I've no objection to people *comments* saying how they interpret the words in context.

Comment: @CopperKettle: Despite my degree being in Lit Crit, I don't know what exactly Keats intends here. The context suggests *threshold* here alludes to the *boundary* between life and death/old age, but I dunno. Maybe this is relevant: [The definition of a **threshold stream** is that the bankfull fluid shear stress is within twenty percent of the critical shear stress. The critical shear stress is the critical fluid shear stress at which the bed particles will begin to move.](http://www.geol.umd.edu/undergraduate/paper/behrns.pdf) (but I kinda doubt it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would be happy to be shown wrong, but somehow I don't think Keats knew the first thing about fluid dynamics or shear stresses. ;)

Comment: @Nathan: He probably knew his Bible though. Including this citation / analysis of the Prophet Ezekiel ... [behold, waters issued out from under the **threshold** of the house ... a **stream** of waters ; to **signify the plenty of graces**, which are derived from God](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22behold+waters+issued+out+from+under+the+threshold+of%22+%22stream%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - genius! Thank you! I bet he read the Bible. I know he  had the habit of rereading Shakespeare time and time again, so he must also had his favorite passages in the Scriptures that he knew by heart.

Comment: [Keats was a critic of religion who eschewed religious ritual before his (tragically premature) death](https://ffrf.org/news/day/dayitems/item/14624-john-keats), but doubtless he was very familiar with the Bible (there not being much else for a "non-science-oriented" man of letters like him to read at the time! :) But if there's an allusion to a "brook/stream" (moat?) at the "threshold" (the Pearly Gates?), I'd have thought it would be just that - an *allusion*. What if any "surface reading" applies is beyond me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Threshold brook* is neither a fixed phrase (to the best of my knowledge it has never appeared in any context other than this) nor an instance or variation of any established 'template' I recognize.

It means exactly what it says: a *brook* somehow associated with a *threshold*.

That of course raises far more questions than it answers; but those questions belong to LitCrit, not ELL.

At any rate, you may rest assured that you understand exactly as much as any ordinary native speaker encountering this poem for the first time.

Comment: Interesting! I was sure it had some simple, down-to-earth meaning easily grasped by native speakers. The poem did not seem to be of the "poetic riddle" kind. D'oh..

Comment: I've just found one interpretation: "[a river that passes by a cottage door](https://books.google.ru/books?id=5MLnr1BvaIEC&lpg=PA490&ots=Rm98uWRhSw&dq=What%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9Cthreshold%20brook%E2%80%9D%20in%20Keats&hl=ru&pg=PA490#v=onepage&q=What%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9Cthreshold%20brook%E2%80%9D%20in%20Keats&f=false)" ("The Works of John Keats", Wordsworth Editions, 1994, page 490)